# Does a lack of verified signatures for Windows Defender indicate malware?

Tags: malware, windows-10

I ran "autoruns" from Windows Sysinternals on a Windows 10 machine, and noticed that the Windows Defender services were marked in red colour, and did not have verified signatures.  I checked these services on another machine and found that they were all verified as expected.

Does this mean the Windows Defender on my machine is malware?  If so, how can I remove it and reinstall a clean Windows Defender?  Running the thorough offline-scan did not help.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Check using `sigtool64` or right click and use “Properties” in explorer. It’s possible that autoruns isn’t correctly handling the signing mechanism. I would expect Defender to be signed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is normal for legitimate applications to appear as "not verified" in *autoruns.exe*. In my experience, this is normal behaviour and I have seen other legit applications that didn't appear as digitally signed. I wouldn't worry too much about what autoruns tells me if I were you.

This is why malware analysis makes use of various tools, either for static or dynamic analysis. There needs to be a much more detailed "inspection" of the characteristics and behaviour of the application to reach a verdict.

Here is a screenshot from my machine, to put your mind at ease:
[image]

What you **CAN** do, is to create some sort of *'saved state'*, to compare your system with at a later time, and possibly detect how a malware gains **persistence**. Remember, if you eliminate a malware's persistence, then you've 'theoretically' eliminated the malware:

1. Run *autoruns.exe* on a "clean" system and let it finish. (If you suspect your system is already infected with malware, then this process won't help you).
2. Click on **File** -> **Save**, and then save the *.arn* file.
3. When at some point you suspect that you have been infected by some malware, then run *autoruns.exe* again and when it finishes, go to **File** -> **Compare** and load the *.arn* file from step 2. If you notice some dodgy Registry entry that you can be **certain** it is not legitimate, then you can safely delete it.

However, this doesn't mean that you'll always be able to see the auto-start registry entry (e.g. see persistence through *RunOnceKey*, rootkit driver infection, etc). Nevertheless, it might help sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

No, Defender is digitally signed. You can check the image by opening its properties in Explorer and check it manually. I found that it is a bug, but [Microsoft hasn't fixed it yet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a7e41613-43aa-4c9b-b117-46d0f9420bf7/windows-defender-executables-publisher-not-verified-microsoft-corporation?forum=autoruns#986960c6-d417-4747-8020-e06f3bf6e1fb).

Comment: yep, it's a bug in autoruns where they flag as "unverified" if it's been signed by Microsoft but is not in a protected system folder.